# CSS SVG+XML - how to edit?

Tags: css, xml, svg

How can I edit a xml svg with a visual tool?  Any online tools out there?

I have this svg in xml format that I copied it from somewhere:

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

I want to change its colour to black or other colours.

```css
.item>a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin-top: -2.5px;
  top: 22.5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="#" class="item">One</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The most obvious choice would be Inkscape but it's a desktop program. In any case, recommend-a-tool-or-library questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I tried it with `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2‌​F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F200‌​0%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3‌​D'0%200%2027%2044'%3‌​E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%‌​2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l‌​-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2‌​.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C‌​22L27%2C22z'%20fill%‌​3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%‌​3C%2Fsvg%3E` and opened it in inskcape but I have an error.

Comment: Well, that's a data URI. Are you asking for a drawing tool or how to decode a data URI into a regular file?

Answer (score 1):

Paste it into a text file named something.svg and open that file in Adobe Illustrator.
or you can convert svg to jpg/png and edit it in photoshop. [convert here](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg)

Comment: paste what in a .svg? I tried it with `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
`  and opened it in inskcape but I have an error.

Comment: the code you are using is not SVG, it's base64. convert base64 to jpg here : https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter